I can't convert the array to an integer value for hline pinescript v5
I can't convert the array to an integer value inside the support and resistance arrays when you draw them with hline.
I have the following error: Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='call 'operator SQBR' (array)'. An argument of 'array' type was used but a 'input float' is expected.
indicator("Supports and Resistances", overlay=true)

// Function to identify and return support and resistance levels
findSupportsAndResistances() =>
    var supportLevels = array.new_float()
    var resistanceLevels = array.new_float()

    // Calculate support and resistance levels
    for i = 4 to 50
        low1 = low[i]
        high1 = high[i]

         // Find local min
        if low1 < low[i-2] and low1 < low[i-3] and low1 < low[i-4] and low1 < low[i-5]
            array.push(supportLevels, low1)
         // Find local max
        else if high1 > high[i-2] and high1 > high[i-3] and high1 > high[i-4] and high1 > high[i-5]
            array.push(resistanceLevels, high1)

    [supportLevels, resistanceLevels]

// Get support and resistance levels
[supports, resistances] = findSupportsAndResistances()

// Draw support and resistance levels
for i = 0 to array.size(supports) - 1
    hline(supports[i], "Support " + str.tostring(i+1), color=color.green)

for i = 0 to array.size(resistances) - 1
    hline(resistances[i], "Resistance " + str.tostring(i+1), color=color.red)

I tried to choose an integer from the array, for hline to use.
